# Select one particular todo id after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I'm creating a simple todo app, I'm getting data as props like this

```
id:"5b3447a7b9d0e02144538972"
text:"biibbb"
```

from GraphQL Server, what i want now is when i click on the checkbox of todo, i want only that particular todo's id to log, however, it is logging the entire ids like this:

```
5b3447a7b9d0e02144538972
5b36ecfdcc8e551bb02b4dac
5b36ed01cc8e551bb02b4dad
5b3702facc8e551bb02b4dae
```

, can someone please suggest.

```
handleCheckBox = index => {
       console.log(index);
  }
  render() {
    const {data: {loading, todos}} = this.props;
    if(loading) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
        <div>
          {todos.map(todo => (
          <List key={todo.id}>
          <Checkbox
                onClick={this.handleCheckBox(todo.id)}
             />
         .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently calling `handleCheckBox` directly in your render method. You want to give a function reference to `onClick`.

So instead of this:

```
<Checkbox onClick={this.handleCheckBox(todo.id)} />
```

Do this:

```
<Checkbox onClick={() => this.handleCheckBox(todo.id)} />
```

Comment: @JasonWilliam Great! Just try to keep in mind that event handlers (`onClick`, `onChange`, ...) wants a function it can call when the event happens. You should not call the event handler function yourself.